# Can Eclipse step into and/or set breakpoints in a PHAR?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, phar

I would like to step through some third-party code that is in a PHAR.  I created the following script in order to attach the debugger.

```
include('third-party\some.phar');
```

The debugger breaks on this line but it will not step into the PHAR.  I get the error `An internal error occurred during: "Debug Source Lookup". java.lang.NullPointerException`.  When I resume debugging the script runs as expected.

I tried adding the PHAR to the project's Libraries and this allowed me to navigate the code in the PHAR.  However, I still cannot set breakpoints or step into the PHAR.

I'm aware that I can extract the PHAR but it has a [Stub](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.stub.php) so I would rather leave it as is.

Comment: Can you explain why having a Stub prevents you from extracting the Phar? (I'm not too familiar with Phar files, and it might be something that others will ask anyway).

Comment: The stub is code that gets executed when you load the PHAR.  It usually contains stuff like `include 'phar://myphar.phar/index.php';` that would need to be edited after extracting the phar.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That doesn't sound too onerous - maybe you can write an automated task to replace the stub with whatever changes are necessary when it is decompressed, to make it simple and repeatable?

Comment: I notice you're using a Java debugger (or is that just your IDE?). Can you use Xdebug? I don't know if that copes with Phar files, but I would imagine it would be more likely to.